# Testing Google Action on Google Home Mini

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I have tried testing my Google Action on Dialogflow, Google Actions Console, as well as Google Assistant app on my phone. However, when I try to test it out on my Google Home device, it just gives me a response of

> "I'm sorry I can't help with that yet."'

My Google Home app is linked to the same account I use for the testing Google Assistant on my phone (which works).

Comment: How are you invoking your action?

Comment: I use the invocation I have defined on the Actions Console. @NickFelker

Comment: what if you use "talk to my test app"?

Comment: Tried it and sadly it still outputs "I'm sorry I can't do that yet" @NickFelker . I'm thinking maybe it can't be tested on the actual home mini without it being published?

Comment: It should definitely run on all surfaces with your account

Comment: @lolhaha did you found the solution?

Comment: You can publish an Alpha version of the app. If you are logged in with the same account on mini, just say talk to <APP NAME> and it should respond on Google home mini.

Comment: I have this same issue.  Works on google assistant app not on google home device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled sign in on dialogflow action then configure the sign in on actions console also.